# How to make post content limited to a character count in a category page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I have several categories, one of which is 'trips away' 
Each post contains a small bio about the trip away. How can I show a category page displaying each of the posts with their title and bio?

The website I am editing is: 
http://thestudentbubble.com/trips-away/

Currently I have the following code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <div class="featured-post">
        <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <div class="scale"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
        <div class="content-list">
            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h1>
            <?php if(!in_category( array( 10,12,13 ) )){ if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } } ?>
            <?php // the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>

                    <div class="decent-comments">
<ul>
    <li>
            <div class="comment">



<?php
$cats = get_the_category();
$category_id = $cats[0]->cat_ID;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category' => $category_id);
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<?php the_content("Continue reading " . the_title('', '', false)); ?>
<?php endforeach; 
 wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


            </div>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>

    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
    </header><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post -->
```

Comment: Typically things have character limits.  But if you wanted to do words you could count by space.

Comment: So how would I add a character limit? :)

Comment: so you want to trim the $post info down to 30 words?

Comment: to about 50 words, so that the whole bio can be seen. but no location nothing else. The bio i currently in a div with a class="bio". Is there a way of maybe only displaying that div? Sorry I'm very new to wordpress and php

Comment: Check out [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/31545) I did on `the_excerpt()`. Should help you out quite a lot

Answer (score 2):

To control the length, you should use the_excerpt instead of the_content. It would return 55 words by default, but you may change it. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your input / post, but it would be something like:

```
$bio = $_POST['bio'];
if (strlen($bio) > 5000) 
{
   $bio = substr($bio, 0, 4997).'...';
}
```

This will trim your string to 5000 characters and add a ... on the end.  If you wanted to do some validation then you could either use Javascript on the field, on the previous page, or you could post to the PHP page and use the same if statement, but return an error instead of trimming it.

Comment: the 'bio' is in the post conntent, but I don't know how to reference / make a connection to the individual posts in the same category. i have the-content() but that shows all the content of the post I only want it to show th first 5000 characters

Comment: You have to figure out which string the bio is being stored in.  I'm guessing it's $post here.  But I don't know if that's an id of the post, the title, or the text itself.  What happens when you do `echo $post;` in the `foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :`?

Comment: it doesnt print anything out, only the very first post name and picture. normally without it,it would print out all of the posts and their titles

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = "xfgnx dfbdf dsfbdfb";
$charLimit = 5;
echo strlen ($c);
echo "<br>";
echo substr($c, $charLimit);
```

this should help

Comment: It'd be better to do this with wp_trim_words() ?

Answer (score 1):

This will limit the post to 50 words. HOWEVER, I would recommend the solution above mine to get a certain amount of characters rather than words, so it will always be the same length. You don't wont 50 words when users are using lots of big words like "Ambidexterity".

```
<?php 
$limit=50;
$post=explode(" ",$post);

if(count($post) > $limit){
    $wholePost="";
    //Get an array of just the first 30
    $post=array_slice(0,$limit);
    foreach($post as $p){
        $wholePost.="$p ";
    }
    $post=$wholePost;
}

?>
```

Comment: It'd be better to do this with wp_trim_words() ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it's a good idea to stick to WordPress methodologies especially where WP based functions already exist for the relevant task.

You should take a look at [wp_trim_words()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

Using this, is as simple as the following

```
<?php $trimmed = wp_trim_words( $text, $num_words = 55, $more = null ); ?>
```

Which could be combined with the following to remove any html from your content:

```
<?php wp_strip_all_tags( $trimmed , $remove_breaks ); ?>
```